# What VFX and video production softwares are used in movies like "Captain America: Civil War" and "Doctor Strange"?

Tags: video, software, visual-effects

I was thinking that for VFX, they used Maya or some other animation software (especially for Dr.Strange) and for the video production, they used Sony Vegas or After Affects. And of course, they might have also made some of the movie visual effects directly from the video production software itself (for example, in AfterEffects you can make VFX in the software itself).

Those were just my guesses, but if you guys have any ideas or links to what VFX and video production softwares were used in Dr.Strange and Civil War, please state them.

Thanks!

Comment: This all changes from film to film depending on who is making it, I know films like the new Starwars and Startrek were both cut on Avid and the effects were done by ILM (plus other smaller houses) it might be worth looking into the companies who did the work such as ILM to find out what they use as a lot use custom builds and inhouse developed software for a lot of the work.

saying that BlackMagic Resolve is normally used for Color Correcting and grading as well as Fusion is becoming popular in FX

Comment: A simple (popular search engine) search "what software does ILM use" brought up a ton of hits on what they use as well as their history, same goes for other films wtih simple searches like "what software was used to edit captain america"

Comment: I bet they use Excel to do the production spreadsheets. Producers love spreadsheets. Probably Word too, unless they went openOffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends from Company to company, there are multiple companies working on multiple shots, or sometime even on the same shots. Because this (sometimes) differs a lot from eachother, it's really hard to give you an answer to this question.

As mentioned, this heavily depends on effects you want to acchieve and the company you work with.

These are some commonly used programms:

- Cinema 4D
- BodyPaint
- AutoCAD
- 3DS Max
- InfraWorks
- Maya
- Mudbox
- Flame
- Smoke
- Softimage
- Mental Ray
- Combustion
- FLIX
- MODO
- MARI
- NUKE
- OCULA
- HIERO
- Katana
- keylight
- Massive Prime
- Massive Jet
- Massiv for Maya
- Ready to run Agents
- Matchmover
- Z-Brush
- Adobe CS6
- Illustrator
- Photoshop
- Flash
- After effects
- Lightroom
- v-Ray for 3DS Max
- Rendermann
- Avid Media Composer
- Avid effects
- davinciresolve
- Houdini
- 3D coat
- topgun
- shotgun Studio
- PF Track
- NURBS
- Filemaker Pro
- vue
- Plant factory
- Ozone
- Carbon scatter
- Lumen RT
- Primatte
- ultimate
- Final Cut Pro
- Qube
- Synth-Eyes
- boujou
- Fusion
- 3D equalizer
- Mantra
- Real Flow
- Fume FX
- BlueArc

I can narrow them down, if you can tell on which effect you are specifically interessted.

Comment: The 3d VFX (fluids, ironman suit, strange's cape etc) for all Marvel movies is handled by Houdini. Editing is Avid. Colour is Resolve.